# Custom identity provider issue on Chrome

Tags: federated-authentication, sso

I had done SSO authentication which is working locally and on-premise, when I deployed on AWS, it was not working on Chrome but working on Mozilla.

```
 public class ProjectIdentityProvider : IdentityProvidersProcessor
    {

        private readonly ICookieManager cookieManager;
       
        public ProjectIdentityProvider(
            FederatedAuthenticationConfiguration federatedAuthenticationConfiguration,
            ICookieManager cookieManager,
            BaseSettings settings) : base(federatedAuthenticationConfiguration, cookieManager, settings)
        {
            this.cookieManager = cookieManager ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(cookieManager));
        }

        protected override void ProcessCore(IdentityProvidersArgs args)
        {
            var authenticationType = this.GetAuthenticationType();
            var identityProvider = this.GetIdentityProvider();
            var saveSigninToken = identityProvider.TriggerExternalSignOut;

            var oidcOptions = this.SetupOidcOptions(authenticationType, saveSigninToken);

            args.App.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(oidcOptions);
        }

        public OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions SetupOidcOptions(
            string authenticationType,
            bool saveSigninToken)
        {
            var oidcOptions = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = authenticationType,
                Authority = authority,
                ClientId = clientId,
                ClientSecret = clientSecret,
                ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdTokenToken,
                RedirectUri = redirectUri,
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,
                Scope = OpenIdConnectScope.OpenIdProfile + " " + OpenIdConnectScope.OfflineAccess,
                SaveTokens = true,
                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                {
                    RedirectToIdentityProvider = this.RedirectToIdentityProviderAsync,
                    SecurityTokenValidated = this.SecurityTokenValidatedAsync,
                    AuthenticationFailed = (context) =>
                    {
                        if (context.Exception.Message.Contains(errorCode))
                        {
                            context.SkipToNextMiddleware();
                        }
                        return Task.FromResult(true);
                    }
                },
                TokenValidationParameters =
            {
                SaveSigninToken = saveSigninToken
            },
            };

            return oidcOptions;
        }

        protected override string IdentityProviderName => "ProjectIdentityProvider";

        protected BaseLog Log { get; }

        public Collection<string> Scopes { get; } = new Collection<string>();

        private Task RedirectToIdentityProviderAsync(
            RedirectToIdentityProviderNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions>
                notification)
        {
            var owinContext = notification.OwinContext;
            var protocolMessage = notification.ProtocolMessage;
            var user = Sitecore.Context.User;
            if (protocolMessage.RequestType == OpenIdConnectRequestType.Authentication)
            {
               
                protocolMessage.RedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri;
            }

            if (protocolMessage.RequestType == OpenIdConnectRequestType.Logout)
            {
                protocolMessage.PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri;
                protocolMessage.IdTokenHint = this.GetIdTokenHint(owinContext);
            }
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        private Task SecurityTokenValidatedAsync(SecurityTokenValidatedNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> notification)
        {
            var identityProvider = this.GetIdentityProvider();
            var identity = notification.AuthenticationTicket.Identity;

            foreach (var current in identityProvider.Transformations)
            {
                current.Transform(identity, new TransformationContext(this.FederatedAuthenticationConfiguration, identityProvider));
            }
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this issue by adding `CookieManager` property like below code:

```
public OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions SetupOidcOptions(
            string authenticationType,
            bool saveSigninToken)
        {
            var oidcOptions = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = authenticationType,
               
                Authority = authority,
                ClientId = clientId,
                ClientSecret = clientSecret,
                
                ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdTokenToken,
                RedirectUri = redirectUri,
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,
               
                Scope = OpenIdConnectScope.OpenIdProfile + " " + OpenIdConnectScope.OfflineAccess,
                SaveTokens = true,
               
                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                {
                    RedirectToIdentityProvider = this.RedirectToIdentityProviderAsync,
                    SecurityTokenValidated = this.SecurityTokenValidatedAsync,
                    AuthenticationFailed = (context) =>
                    {
                        if (context.Exception.Message.Contains(errorCode))
                        {
                            context.HandleResponse();
                            context.OwinContext.Authentication.Challenge();
                        }
                        return Task.FromResult(true);
                    }
                },
                TokenValidationParameters =
            {
                SaveSigninToken = saveSigninToken
                 
            },
            CookieManager = cookieManager
            };

            return oidcOptions;
        }
```